# Endless road animation CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have this 2D Highway background image
https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/background-1_0.png

I'm working on a mobile game (with JS and CSS3) of racing cars,
and I want to make animation of this road to make an illusion of movement

Can someone please guide me what's the best practice for this case?

Currently I do something like that, but it's not smooth enough (especially in mobile browser) -

```
.main {
    background-image: url(https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/background-1_0.png);
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-size: 103%;
    background-repeat-y: repeat;
    background-position-y: 27px;
    animation: loopingRoad 0.1s infinite;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```
@keyframes loopingRoad {
    100% {
      background-position-y: 1000%;
    }
    0% {
      background-position-y: 0%
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
background-position: 0 0;
background-position: 0 -100000px;
```

as the keyFrame keys:

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main {
    background-image: url(https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/background-1_0.png);
    background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
    background-size: 103%;
    background-repeat-y: repeat;
    background-position-y: 27px;
    animation: loopingRoad 250s linear infinite;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


@keyframes loopingRoad {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 0 -100000px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main" />
```

Comment: But this does glitch every 500sec. That isnt very bad, depends on the usecase I guess

Comment: @Martijn what browser are you using? Looks fine in Chrome

Comment: @Sean I'm using Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Create a container in which you set the aspect ratio that corresponds with the road image. This allows you to play with the width of the container while keeping the image in the right proportions.

For the image itself. Make it twice the height of the container. This allows you to transform the entire road 50% upwards. When starting the animation, the top half of the road is exposed. At the end of the animation the bottom half is exposed. Loop this proces to create the illusion.

The `transform` property animates very well as it doesn't ask the browser to repaint the entire page, but only the element that is transformed.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.view {
  max-width: 840px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.road {
  aspect-ratio: 840 / 650; /* Dimensions of the road image */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.road::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  animation: loopRoad 1.5s infinite linear;
  height: 200%; /* Twice the height */
  background-size: auto 50%; /* Fit into 1 vertical half */
  background-image: url(https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/background-1_0.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

@keyframes loopRoad {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="view">
  <div class="road"></div>
</div>
```